# Cypress> finding text in an array of objects > Cannot locate text:TypeError: $e1.find.contains is not a function

Tags: javascript, arrays, automation, cypress

I'm having a problem with my array.  I can't find a specific piece of text even though I've done an algortithmn

[Click this link for the video.](https://www.dropbox.com/s/5ggxhqxjrtzkqul/Array.mp4?dl=0)

I'm getting 200 status for everything, which is perfect.  However, when I try to find a specific item (cashews) I am getting an error message.

Here is code:

```
/// <reference types="Cypress" />

describe('My first test suite', function() 
{
//all tests cases go inside of this area

it('Open web page', function()   {

  cy.visit("https://rahulshettyacademy.com/seleniumPractise/#/")
  cy.wait(2000)
  cy.get('.search-keyword').type('ca')
  cy.get('.product:visible').should('have.length',4)
  //parent child elements 
  cy.get('.products').find('.product').should('have.length',4)
  cy.get('.products').find('.product').eq(2).contains('ADD TO CART').click()

  //iterate over an array of ojbects using using each
  cy.get('.products').find('.product').each(($e1, index, $list)=> {

    const textVeg=$e1.find('h4.product-name').text()
    if(textVeg.includes('Cashews'))
    {
      $e1.find.contains('ADD TO CART').click()
      //$e1.find('button')
    }    
  })    

H

})//end of my first test case
```

Here is the text from the cypress log file:

```
TypeError: $e1.find.contains is not a function
```

What did I do wrong in this algorithm?

Answer (score 1):

You can use cypress command [wrap](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/wrap.html#Syntax) to replace

$e1.find.contains('ADD TO CART').click()

with

```
cy.wrap($e1).contains('ADD TO CART').click()
```

Comment: Thank you.  I will try it and let you know